# Oracle converting working SQL with CTE to procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, procedure

I have some SQL code, which works as designed. I'm trying to convert the code to a procedure to make it flexible so that different values maybe passed in.

I am running into an error while trying to create the procedure.

```
Errors: PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX
Line/Col: 28/1 PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Line/Col: 37/3 PL/SQL: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

The problem seems to be occurring in a CTE, which contains a SELECT so I'm a bit confused and can use some assistance.

Below is a test CASE that contains the working SQL along with the procedure I'm trying to create.

Thanks in advance for your help, patience and expertise and to all who answer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

create table schedule(
       schedule_id NUMBER(4),
       location_id number(4),
       base_date DATE,
       start_date DATE,
       end_date DATE,
         CONSTRAINT start_min check (start_date=trunc(start_date,'MI')),   
       CONSTRAINT end_min check (end_date=trunc(end_date,'MI')),
 CONSTRAINT end_gt_start CHECK (end_date >= start_date),
CONSTRAINT same_day CHECK (TRUNC(end_date) = TRUNC(start_date))
      );
/

    CREATE TABLE locations AS
    SELECT level AS location_id,
       'Door ' || level AS location_name,

    CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'T' 
         END AS location_type

    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 15;


     ALTER TABLE locations 
         ADD ( CONSTRAINT locations_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (location_id));


-- works fine

WITH  params  AS
(
    SELECT  1 AS schedule_id,

TO_DATE ( '2021-08-21 00:00:00'
            , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
            )             AS base_date
    ,    INTERVAL '83760' SECOND          AS offset
    ,    INTERVAL '10' MINUTE           AS incr
    ,    INTERVAL '5' MINUTE         AS duration
    FROM    dual
)
SELECT   p.schedule_id
,               l.location_id
,      p.base_date
,      p.base_date + offset
              + (incr * (ROWNUM - 1)) AS start_date
,      p.base_date + offset
              + (incr * (ROWNUM - 1))
            + p.duration         AS end_date
FROM      locations l
CROSS JOIN params   p
ORDER BY  start_date
;

-- having problem 

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX
 (
  i_schedule_id IN PLS_INTEGER,
  i_base_date IN DATE,
  i_offset IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
i_incr IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10,
  i_duration         IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 5
)
 AS 
 
l_offset  interval day to second;
   l_incr interval day to second;
  l_duration interval day to second;


BEGIN
 
l_offset :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_offset, 'SECOND') ;

l_incr :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_incr, 'MINUTE') ;

l_duration :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_duration, 'MINUTE') ;


WITH params AS(
SELECT 
   i_schedule_id 
  ,i_base_date
  ,l_offset
  ,l_incr
  ,l_duration
FROM DUAL
)

INSERT INTO schedule(
        schedule_id
      ,location_id
      ,base_date
      ,start_date
      ,end_date
  )
  VALUES 
  (p.schedule_id 
   ,l.location_id 
   ,p.base_date
   ,start_date 
   ,end_date 
);

SELECT   p.schedule_id
,               l.location_id
,      p.base_date
,      p.base_date + p.offset
              + (p.incr * (ROWNUM - 1)) AS start_date
,      p.base_date + p.offset
              + (p.incr * (ROWNUM - 1))
            + p.duration         AS end_date
FROM      locations l
CROSS JOIN params   p
ORDER BY  start_date;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is this statement.

```
WITH params AS(
SELECT 
   i_schedule_id 
  ,i_base_date
  ,l_offset
  ,l_incr
  ,l_duration
FROM DUAL
)

INSERT INTO schedule(
        schedule_id
      ,location_id
      ,base_date
      ,start_date
      ,end_date
  )
  VALUES 
  (p.schedule_id 
   ,l.location_id 
   ,p.base_date
   ,start_date 
   ,end_date 
);
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Syntactically, if you want to have a CTE as part of an `insert`, you'd want to do an `insert ... select`

```
INSERT INTO schedule(
        schedule_id
      ,location_id
      ,base_date
      ,start_date
      ,end_date
  )
WITH params AS(
SELECT 
   i_schedule_id 
  ,i_base_date
  ,l_offset
  ,l_incr
  ,l_duration
FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
    p.schedule_id 
   ,l.location_id 
   ,p.base_date
   ,start_date 
   ,end_date 
  FROM params p;
```

From there, though, you've still got several syntax issues that it's not obvious how you'd want to solve all of them.

- `p.schedule_id` isn't valid because there is no `schedule_id` column in the `params` CTE.  My guess is that you want to alias `i_schedule_id` to `schedule_id` in the CTE.
- `l.location_id` doesn't make sense because you're not selecting from a table that could plausibly be given an alias of `l`.
- There is no `base_date`, `start_date`, or `end_date` column in your `params` CTE.  And it's not obvious how you'd plausibly fix that.

Maybe you actually intended the subsequent `select` statement to actually be part of this `insert` statement despite the fact that you terminated the `insert` with a semicolon?  If so, maybe you want

```
    INSERT INTO schedule(
            schedule_id
          ,location_id
          ,base_date
          ,start_date
          ,end_date
      )
    WITH params AS(
    SELECT 
       i_schedule_id schedule_id
      ,i_base_date base_date
      ,l_offset offset
      ,l_incr incr
      ,l_duration duration
    FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT   p.schedule_id
,               l.location_id
,      p.base_date
,      p.base_date + p.offset
              + (p.incr * (ROWNUM - 1)) AS start_date
,      p.base_date + p.offset
              + (p.incr * (ROWNUM - 1))
            + p.duration         AS end_date
FROM      locations l
CROSS JOIN params   p
ORDER BY  start_date;
```

That would produce code that compiles at least.  There doesn't, however, appear to be any reason to bother with a CTE here at all.  Just reference the local variables and input parameters directly.  I've also eliminated the `order by` since it doesn't make sense in the context of an `insert` statement.  I assume there is a reason that you need to take input parameters as integers and convert them to local variables with the same name and a different data type rather than just passing in `interval` parameters to the procedure.  If you can do that, you can further simplify things by eliminating the local variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_XXX
 (
  i_schedule_id IN PLS_INTEGER,
  i_base_date IN DATE,
  i_offset IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
i_incr IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10,
  i_duration         IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 5
)
 AS 
 
l_offset  interval day to second;
   l_incr interval day to second;
  l_duration interval day to second;


BEGIN
 
l_offset :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_offset, 'SECOND') ;

l_incr :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_incr, 'MINUTE') ;

l_duration :=
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_duration, 'MINUTE') ;


        INSERT INTO schedule(
                schedule_id
              ,location_id
              ,base_date
              ,start_date
              ,end_date
          )
    SELECT   i_schedule_id
    ,        l.location_id
    ,        i_base_date
    ,      i_base_date + l_offset
                  + (l_incr * (ROWNUM - 1)) AS start_date
    ,      i_base_date + l_offset
                  + (l_incr * (ROWNUM - 1))
                + l_duration         AS end_date
    FROM      locations l;
END;
/
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, detailed explanation and expertise this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish